# A ranking field in SP2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list

We have a list containing items classified by one field – “Category”.

We have a “Ranking” field for users to rank list items in a category.

We want the “Ranking” field to function like the column ordering section of list settings.

A user has ranked items as 1-5. They want to change the item ranked as “4” to a ranking of “2”. We would like the other items in the category to renumber reflecting that change.

Ideally, we would like this to work with inline editing within the list, instead of having to open the list item.

We’re using InfoPath 2010 for initial entry into the list. If we have to, we could use an InfoPath form for editing, but I would prefer to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what type of list you are using, here are a few potential approaches:

1. Links list: you can reorder items by clicking on the Items tab and then Change Item Order.
2. Another type of list (but not a document library): you can install the feature from [this article](http://spyralout.com/2010/08/06/reordering-list-items/), and then sort just like you would with a links list. (You could also enable attachments via List Advanced Settings instead of using a doc library.)
3. If you have to use a document library, or the above are not sufficient, you may want to consider this [custom field](http://sp2010order.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thank you - I've asked our enterprise team to explore the feature you mentioned. We'll see if they let me have it.